# Sharepoint Document Library OnQuickLaunch (in site navigation) with Graph API?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I'm currently working with SPO and Microsoft Graph API on a .NET 6.0 microservice.
What I want to achieve is to create a Document Library and to have a link to it in the quick navigation on the left.

I can create the Document library successfully like this:

[image]

But the created document library is only visible in the "Site Contents" section.
What the user's I'm developing for would like to have is, as simple as: EVERY TIME a new Document Library is programmatically created a link to it SHOWS up in the navigation pane.

From a user perspective this is easily achievable from the UI:

[image]

It's just a tick.

With fiddler I saw the body of the request made when you create a Document Library via UI:

[image]

**But what's the corresponding property of this simple "OnQuickLaunch" field in the Graph API list model?**

I've been unable to find any reference from MS documentation, am I blind or missing something?

Would also be ok if should be, somehow, possible to add the link in the navigation pane "manually" from code via Graph API.
Something like:

`POST microsoft.graph.com/v1/quickLaunch/links`

with body:

```
{
"name":"myLink",
"url":"the/document/library/url"
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Microsoft Graph API - Document library creation with navigation link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53766605/microsoft-graph-api-document-library-creation-with-navigation-link)

Comment: @user2250152 yes and no, the issue seems to be the same but the answer (dated end of 2018) doesn't solve the problem; it seems like MS didn't covered this scenario so far.

Comment: I've checked the doc for beta version: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/sitepage?view=graph-rest-beta but I don't see any property related to quick launch or link